# How to build Rest API which accepts xml / Json data as POST data in c# MVC?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

public HttpResponseMessage Hello(??????)
        {

```
        try
        {
```

something........

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation to use ASP.NET WEB API for purposes like this: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: In a given video it accepts JSON of type Person. because he already know's  the structure of person . but i want a POST method which accepts any type of given JSON , not pre structured .